# Pulling everything till a specific commit in git

Tags: git

I've two servers - Staging and Live.
I keep my staging server up-to-date so it has all the latest changes push to my git repo.
Now I want to update my Live server but I don't want to pull everything from my repo but only till a specific commit.

When I do

```
git status
```

it says

```
# git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 21 commits.
#
```

When I do

```
git checkout 7c7f78382fgh9e642d9b3298acacc5903410fefa
```

I get an error...

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: 7c7f78382fgh9e642d9b3298acacc5903410fefa
```

Any idea what can be wrong.

Do I need to pull everything latest and then do checkout ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused - why is the live server 21 commits _ahead_ of the remote?

Comment: I never make any changes on the server so I've never committed or pushed anything from the server. Not sure why is it saying that.

Comment: I just did git log on the Live server and I've made 49 commits after the latest revision on the Live server. I want to include next 35 commits in it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clearer, you should actually check out a hash to a branch, otherwise you'll be in a detached head state.

```
git fetch origin                        # Fetches commits from the remote repository
git checkout -b new_branch_name 7c7f783 # creates a new branch from this commit.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the remote commits before you can use them.

On your production server:

```
git fetch origin                                      # Fetches commits from the remote repository
git checkout 7c7f78382fgh9e642d9b3298acacc5903410fefa # Moves forward to the relevant one
```